# Unexpected return values in my own take on Array.reduce() with Array.from(string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic, reduce

I wanted to try my hand at writing my own reduce function, however the result t I'm getting when I pass a string is very strange.

```
const _ = {};

_.reduce = (collection, callback, accumulator) => {
  if(Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      let value = collection[i];
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, value, i);
      console.log(accumulator, i);
    }
  } else if (typeof collection === 'object') {
    for (const key in collection) {
      let value = collection[key];
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, value, key);
    }
  } else {
    // hanlde things that can be converted to an array
    try {
      _.reduce(Array.from(collection), callback, accumulator);
    } catch(e) {
      throw 'not iterable';
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
};
```

The following works:

```
_.reduce(Array.from("banana"), (string, letter) => {
  return string + letter;
}, "");
// -> "banana" === expected result
```

However when I pass the string `"banana"` directly and leave the type converting to the function's Array.from it does not seem to work for some reason.

```
_.reduce("banana", (string, letter) => {
  return string + letter;
}, "");
// -> "" ???
```

It's probably something less obvious I'm not seeing here, so if anyone can find the error then that would be very helpful.

Comment: "does not seem to work" really doesn't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Quick way to convert to array is with spread operator .... `_.reduce([..."banana"], `

Comment: The problem is that an empty string is returned. I also just put a console.log before ```return accumulator``` and it seems to execute that twice @Pointy

Comment: @Veinq well in that last `else` clause, shouldn't you assign the return value of `_.reduce()` back to `accumulator`?

Comment: Thank you @Pointy that did the trick. I can't believe I didn't catch that. Do you have any idea why it gets to ```return accumulator``` twice?.
(edit) I fixed that by returning immediately in the try block.

Comment: `return accumulator` is actually called twice: 1. Within the `_.reduce` call in your `_.reduce`  method and 2. In the "main" call of your `_.reduce` `method.

Comment: In javascript, primitive types are passed to function by-value, and string is a primitive type.  So, string cannot be used as an accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the result to `accumulator`.

```js
const _ = {};

_.reduce = (collection, callback, accumulator) => {
  if(Array.isArray(collection)) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      let value = collection[i];
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, value, i);
    }
  } else if (typeof collection === 'object') {
    for (const key in collection) {
      let value = collection[key];
      accumulator = callback(accumulator, value, key);
    }
  } else {
    // hanlde things that can be converted to an array
    try {
      // FIX
      accumulator = _.reduce(Array.from(collection), callback, accumulator);
    } catch(e) {
      throw 'not iterable';
    }
  }
  return accumulator;
};

var result = _.reduce(Array.from("banana"), (string, letter) => {
  return string + letter;
}, "");

console.log("Result for Array.from('banana'):", result);

result = _.reduce("banana", (string, letter) => {
  return string + letter;
}, "");
console.log("Result for 'banana':", result);
```